# Fastest way to look up value in previous period?

Tags: r, data.table, benchmarking, lookup

I have a dataset of household retail purchases of products. For each household trip, I would like to look up whether any brands purchased during that trip by that household were purchased in the previous period - if so, loyal=1 else loyal=0. I have a large dataset with billions of observations, so the more efficient the better. :)

```
library(data.table)
household <-  as.integer(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3))
trip      <- as.integer(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9))
brand     <- as.integer(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,1,6,8,9,9,2,8,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,1,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,1,8,9,2))
DT <- data.table(household,trip,brand)
```

Desired output:

```
> DT
             household trip loyal
[1,]         1        1    NA
[2,]         1        2     0
[3,]         1        3     1
[4,]         2        4    NA
[5,]         2        5     0
[6,]         2        6     0
[7,]         3        7    NA
[8,]         3        8     1
[9,]         3        9     1
```

I tried something like this but it's obviously not producing the desired output.

```
DT$loyal <- 0
for (h in unique(DT$household)){
  for (t in unique(DT$trip)){
    DT[brand %in% (DT[trip=t-1]$brand)]$loyal <- 1
  }}
```

Comment: Minor point: don't use `cbind` on columns to build a table, just do `data.table(household, trip, loyal)`. Also, using integers for integer-like numbers will usually speed stuff up.

Comment: thanks, I've corrected it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self join in order to get an index and then join again to a unique combination of `household` and `trip`. This comes to mind

```
# Create a column of the previous trip
DT[, prev_trip := trip - 1L]

# Self join
indx <- 
  DT[DT 
   ,.(household, trip)
   ,on = .(household, prev_trip = trip, brand)
   ,nomatch = 0L]

# A unique combination `household` and `trip` joined with the index
res <- unique(DT[, .(household, trip)])[indx, on = .(household, trip), loyal := 1L]
res
#    household trip loyal
# 1:         1    1    NA
# 2:         1    2    NA
# 3:         1    3     1
# 4:         2    4    NA
# 5:         2    5    NA
# 6:         2    6    NA
# 7:         3    7    NA
# 8:         3    8     1
# 9:         3    9     1
```

Not sure if the 0 are critical there as they don't look very informative to me but it is easy to add them later if needed

Comment: Alternate self-join: `DT[, loyal_brand := .SD[.(household = household, trip = trip - 1L, brand = brand), on=.(household, trip, brand), .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L]; DT[, loyal := any(loyal_brand), by=.(household, trip)]`

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.